# How to access the properties of image declared in subclass of UIImageView in other controller class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have made a class which is subclass of UIImageView. There are properties like imageFrame, centrePoint and an array. Now I have to initialize the frame of UIImageView and access it in other class so how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the native UIImageView `frame` and `center`, since your class is a subclass of UIImageView, e.g., `yourUIImageViewSubclass.frame = CGRectMake(...`

If you really want to use your own property, you could access the underlying native property in your property accessors, e.g.,

```
- (CGRect)imageFrame
{
   // other code go here

   return self.frame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but initialize an instance of your class like this:

```
SomeSubclass *foo = [[SomeSubclass alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 20, 20)];
```

Add it to the `superView`:

```
[self.view addSubview:foo];
```

Access the exposed properties:

```
foo.myArray ...
foo.frame ...
```

Comment: Glad I could help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept the best answer as correct. Happy coding :)